# Architecture of a static source code for three different technologi?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, asp.net-mvc

If you create a webbapplication in asp.net mvc and also should be working for Iphone and android.

If you have a static source code in C# and you cannot apply as a SQL code and this statistic  code is needed for Iphone and android, does it mean that I need to have three different source code based on same code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.

In an MVC web application, the only code/languages that the device needs to understand are common, e.g. HTML, Javascript, CSS, etc.  Any c# or SQL code in your project is executed on the web server, not on the device.  The web server, of course, has a single code base.

Comment: Are you telling me that android and ipohne should have access to the single code base in order to use a specific static code?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "specific static code."  MVC web applications do not execute on the device and therefore do not need access to the executable code that drives the web site.  With a web application, the device's browser makes an HTTP request to the web server, which executes the code and serves up a document, which is then parsed and displayed by the device.

Comment: If have a source code, not sql code, that is need to be used in ASP.net mvc, android and  Iphone, how should I do it?

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Source code is not executed or distributed (typically object code or precompiled code is instead).  I think you mean to say that you have common *functionality*, not necessarily common source code.  Provision of common functionality is a very broad question and there are any number of solutions, e.g. you could implement the functionality three times (once on each platform), implement it once and compile with three different targets, or use some sort of RPC or AJAX and keep the functionality in one place.  Suggest you post a more specific question.